# JUnit 5 Annotations - Not Working with LiveData / Parameterized Tests

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing, junit5, mockk

## Overview

**Expected Behavior**

Replace mock object initialization using the `mockObject` function [implementation](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/mocking-is-not-rocket-science-mockk-advanced-features-42277e5983b5#d73e) with annotation syntax initialization for JUnit 5 as outlined in the [documentation](https://mockk.io/#junit5) and [Medium post](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/mocking-is-not-rocket-science-mockk-features-e5d55d735a98#d564) by [@oleksiyp](https://github.com/oleksiyp).

**Current Behavior**

The test in question is a [parameterized test](https://phauer.com/2018/best-practices-unit-testing-kotlin/#data-classes-for-parameterized-tests) as outlined by [@phauer](https://github.com/phauer) for JUnit 5 which seems to conflict with `@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)`. In order to implement tests with LiveData the test must run synchronously in the local unit test using this [`InstantExecutorExtension`](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2019/01/17/livedatajunit5#junit-5) designed by [@JeroenMols](https://github.com/JeroenMols).

Mock object initialization works as expected with the `mockObject` function, but fails using the annotation `@MockK`.

## Error

Warning message/Build fail:

> Repeatable annotations with non-SOURCE retention are not yet supported.

## Implementation

**`mockObject` function implementation (Working as expected)**

```
@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class)
class NavigateContentTests {
    private val mainThreadSurrogate = newSingleThreadContext("UI thread")
    private val contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()

    // This is the stream of tests to run in the Parameterized test below.
    private fun NavigateContent() = Stream.of(
            NavigateContentTest(
                    isRealtime = false,
                    feedType = MAIN,
                    timeframe = DAY,
                    mockFeedList = mockDbContentListForDay,
                    mockContent = mockArticleContent),
            ...)

    @BeforeAll
    fun beforeAll() { mockkObject(ContentRepository) }

    @AfterAll
    fun afterAll() { unmockkAll() // Re-assigns transformation of object to original state prior to mock. }

    @BeforeEach
    fun beforeEach() { Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate) }

    @AfterEach
    fun afterEach() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain() // Reset main dispatcher to the original Main dispatcher.
        mainThreadSurrogate.close()
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("NavigateContent")
    fun `Navigate Content`(test: NavigateContentTest) = runBlocking {
        every { ContentRepository.getMainFeedList(test.isRealtime, any()) } returns mockGetMainFeedList(
                test.mockFeedList, CONTENT)
        every {
            ContentRepository.queryLabeledContentList(test.feedType)
        } returns mockQueryMainContentList(test.mockFeedList)
        every { ContentRepository.getContent(test.mockContent.id) } returns mockGetContent(test)
        // Tests here...
        // Verification here...
    }
}
```

**Annotation syntax initialization (Not working due to two extensions `@ExtendWith`)**

```
@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class)
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
class NavigateContentTests {

    // This object should be mocked.
    @MockK
    lateinit var contentRepository: ContentRepository

    private val mainThreadSurrogate = newSingleThreadContext("UI thread")
    private val contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()

    // This is the stream of tests to run in the Parameterized test below.
    private fun NavigateContent() = Stream.of(
            NavigateContentTest(
                    isRealtime = false,
                    feedType = MAIN,
                    timeframe = DAY,
                    mockFeedList = mockDbContentListForDay,
                    mockContent = mockArticleContent),
            ...)

    @BeforeAll
    fun beforeAll() {  MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true) // turn relaxUnitFun on for }

    @AfterAll
    fun afterAll() { unmockkAll() // Re-assigns transformation of object to original state prior to mock. }

    @BeforeEach
    fun beforeEach() { Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate) }

    @AfterEach
    fun afterEach() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain() // Reset main dispatcher to the original Main dispatcher.
        mainThreadSurrogate.close()
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("NavigateContent")
    fun `Navigate Content`(test: NavigateContentTest) = runBlocking {
        every { contentRepository.getMainFeedList(test.isRealtime, any()) } returns mockGetMainFeedList(
                test.mockFeedList, CONTENT)
        every {
            contentRepository.queryLabeledContentList(test.feedType)
        } returns mockQueryMainContentList(test.mockFeedList)
        every { contentRepository.getContent(test.mockContent.id) } returns mockGetContent(test)
        // Tests here...
        // Verification here...
    }
}
```

## Environment

- MockK version: 1.9.3
- OS: Mac 10.14.6
- Kotlin version: 1.3.50
- JDK version: 12.0.1
- JUnit version: 5.5.1
- Type of test: Unit test

Comment: Try to combine @ExtendsWith.. 
@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class)
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)

Into combined way:
**@ExtendWith({InstantExecutorExtension::class, MockKExtension::class})**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug according to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/364), as documented by the MockK creator, [@oleksiy](https://github.com/oleksiyp).

I will update this post once I see the bug is resolved.